# How do I sort string of arrays based on length THEN Alphabetic order?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am doing this due to a site where i learn programming and I simply cannot wrap my head around this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n;
    string thename;
    vector <pair<string,int>> name;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> thename;
        name.push_back(make_pair(thename, thename.length()));
    }
    sort(name.begin(), name.end());
    sort(name.begin(), name.end(),
     [](const pair<string, int>& lhs, const pair<string, int>& rhs) {
             return lhs.second < rhs.second; } );
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << name[i].first<< endl;
    }
}
```

I am advised by my senior to not use the lambda sort because I myself still don't understand it very well. But I will still accept any lambda sort answer.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `std::sort` is not stable - this means that when you sort by the length, you destroy the sorting by the name.

The *easy* way to do this, is reverse your pair.  `std::pair` has an [`operator <`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) which compares `first` values, and if they are the same compares the `second` value.  So what you need is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int n;
    vector <pair<int,string>> name;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string thename;
        cin >> thename;
        name.push_back(make_pair(thename.length(),thename));
    }
    sort(name.begin(), name.end());
    for (const auto& n: name)
    {
        cout << n.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Note I have moved `thename` inside the loop (it is never used outside), and made the final for loop a foreach loop (which should be your prefer loop form where possible).

**However** you don't need to store the lengths in the vector.  You can  just store the names, and then use a custom comparator to do the comparison.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int n;
    vector<string> name;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string thename;
        cin >> thename;
        name.push_back(thename);
    }
    sort(name.begin(), name.end(),
        [](const string& lhs, const string& rhs)
        {
            return std::tie(lhs.length(),lhs) < std::tie(rhs.length(), rhs); 
        } );
    for (const auto& n : name)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

Note that I have used `std::tie` to compare both length and string.  The advantage over `std::make_pair` is that it will default to using a reference, and hence not copying the string.  The advantage over doing it yourself is that it is *hugely* easier to get right (and it's easier to read too).

Note that you might replace the lambda

```
[](const string& lhs, const string& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.length(),lhs) < std::tie(rhs.length(), rhs); 
}
```

by a functor manually written:

```
struct MyLessString
{
    bool operator () (const string& lhs, const string& rhs) const
    {
        return std::tie(lhs.length(),lhs) < std::tie(rhs.length(), rhs); 
    }
};
```

and use it:

```
sort(name.begin(), name.end(), MyLessString{});
```

Comment: `std::tie` or `std::make_pair(lhs.length(), std::cref(lhs))` would avoid to copy the `std::string`

Comment: @Jarod42 : Ooh!  I didn't know std:tie did that.  Editted.  Thank you.  (It now removes the only plausible reason for a hand-written comparison on this case).

Comment: @Jarod42 : D'oh!  Thanks for that.

Comment: Man, My Senior was right about me not using lambda sort for the moment ._.
for (const auto& n : name)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
How does this work if i may ask? >-<

Comment: Look at *"for range"* for `for (const auto& elem : container)`.

Comment: Just a note, in gcc 11.4.0 the above generates a compile error I had to do: 
 size_t s1 = lhs.size();
 size_t s2 = rhs.size();
 return (std::tie(s1, lhs) < std::tie(s2, rhs));

Answer (score 5):

You do not need a `vector<pair<int,string>` to store your array of strings, you can a `vector<string>` and write an appropriate sorting function here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    int n;
    std::string thename;
    std::vector <std::string> name;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> thename;
        name.push_back(thename);
    }
    sort(name.begin(), name.end(),
     [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) {
             return lhs.size() == rhs.size() ? 
                    lhs < rhs : lhs.size() < rhs.size(); } );
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << name[i]<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

input:

```
4
Joe
Ann
Ralph
Andrew
```

output:

```
Ann
Joe
Ralph
Andrew
```

Comment: alternatively `return std::tie(lhs.size(), lhs) < std::tie(rhs.size(), rhs);`

Comment: @Caleth: That won't compile, because `std::tie` does not work with r-values.

Answer (score 1):

I propose [pidgeonhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort) sort followed by a sort of each pidgenhole.

The initial step is only O(N+n) followed by sorting each pidgeonhole in O( p log p), as each p <= n the total sort time should be less or equal to O(n log n)

Warning untested code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

constexpr const int MaxNameLength = 32; // arbitrary chosen length

int main () {
    int n;
    string thename;
    vector <vector<string>> name;
    int maxLen = MaxNameLength;
    name.resize(MaxNameLength);
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> thename;
        if (name.length() > maxLen) {
          name.resize(thename.length()); 
          maxLen = thename.length();
        }
        name[thename.length()].emplace_back(thename);
    }

    for (auto& len: name) {
      sort(len.begin(), len.end());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << name[i].first<< endl;
    }
}
```